# Most efficient way to remove duplicates

Tags: python-3.x

I have a log file that I need to remove duplicate entries from. Each line in the file consists of three parts separated by commas, let's call them A, B and C respectively.

Two entries are duplicates if and only if their A's and C's are equal. If duplicates are found, the one with the greatest B shall remain.

The real log file has a large number of lines, the following serves only as a simplified example:

Log file (input):

```
hostA, 1507300700.0, xyz
hostB, 1507300700.0, abc
hostB, 1507300800.0, xyz
hostA, 1507300800.0, xyz
hostA, 1507300900.0, xyz
```

Log file after duplicates have been removed (output):

```
hostB, 1507300700.0, abc
hostB, 1507300800.0, xyz
hostA, 1507300900.0, xyz
```

I've tried reading in the file as two lists, then comparing them along the lines of:

```
for i in full_log_list_a:
    for j in full_log_list_b:
        if i[0] == j[0] and i[2] == j[2] and i[1] > j[1]:
            print(', '.join(i[0]), file=open(new_file, 'a'))
```

I've also tried a few other things, but whatever I do it ends up iterating over the list too many times and creating a bunch of repeat entries, or it fails to find ONLY the item with the greatest B.  I know there's probably an obvious answer, but I'm stuck. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Every sub-step of a sane approach will be based on sorting (and not necessarily a nested loop). Look up set-intersection algorithms (and maybe nested sorting / stable sorting). Most sane approaches also will make use of either numpy or pandas (although python brings all the necessary components too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a dict is what you're looking for, instead of lists.

As you read the log file you add entries to the dict, where each entry consists of a key (A, C) and a value B. If a key already exists, you compare B with the value mapped to the key, and remap the key if necessary (i.e. if B is greater than the value currently mapped to the key).

Example (do use better names for variables a, b and c):

```
log_file_entries = {}

with open(log_file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        a, b_str, c = line.split(', ')
        b = int(b_str)

        if (a, c) in log_file_entries:
            if b < log_file_entries[(a, c)]:
                continue

        log_file_entries[(a, c)] = b
```

It's one loop. Since the required operations on dicts are (typically) constant in time, i.e. O(1), the overall [time complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) will be O(n), much better than your nested loops' time complexity of O(n²).

When you later rewrite the file, you can just loop over the dict like so:

```
with open(new_file, 'a') as f:
    for (a, c), b in log_file_entries.items():
        print('{0}, {1}, {2}'.format(a, b, c), file=f)
```

Apologies if any code or terms are incorrect, I haven't touched Python in a while.

(P.S. In your example code you use two lists, whereas you could have used the same list in both loops.)

---

**UPDATE**

If you want the value of a key to contain every part of a line in the log file, you could rewrite the above code like so:

```
log_file_entries = {}

with open(log_file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        a, b_str, c = line.split(', ')
        b = int(b_str)

        if (a, c) in log_file_entries:
            if b < log_file_entries[(a, c)][1]:
                continue

        log_file_entries[(a, c)] = (a, b, c)

with open(new_file, 'a') as f:
    for entry in log_file_entries.values():
        print(', '.join(entry), file=f)
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, I should have been using a dict.  I've modified what you supplied to use the `k, v` to look up to full line in the original list (to get all the other fields in the log).  It looks like it's working, but is there a way for me to just do all of that in that single loop you wrote?

Comment: @DavidJ. I'm not sure I understand what you mean. You want a key to be mapped to every part of a line in the log file? E.g., you want (a, c) to be mapped to (a, b, c)? I've updated the answer. In case I misunderstood you, please ask again.

Comment: This is great.  Thanks for the answer and the update!